# Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap, centos5

When I do a ldap search using the command Ldapserach -x -b 'dc=domain,dc=com''(objectclass=*)'  it gives an error stating ldap_bind: Can't contact LDAP server (-1).

I am doing a ldap search on the centos server.

Answer (score 3):

Try either giving ldapsearch the `-h <hostname> or -H <uri>`
options, pointing ldapsearch to the host your ldap server is running on.

Alternatively, ldapsearch will look in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` (RedHat), `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` (Debian) or `${HOME}/.ldaprc`, for directions on what to assume for -H/-h (among other things) by default. (See man 5 ldap.conf for the syntax of .ldaprc/ldap.conf)